# how to use a win32 api SendMessageA in ctypes, Python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes, pywin32

I got this problem, the prototype of this function is like this

```
LRESULT WINAPI SendMessage(
    _In_  HWND hWnd,
    _In_  UINT Msg,
    _In_  WPARAM wParam,
    _In_  LPARAM lParam
);
```

And I did this in python

```
SendMessageA = ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageA
# hwnd here is already got by EnumWindows or FindWindowA

SendMessageA(hwnd, KEY, 0, 0)
```

edit:
can anyone make an example based on the code I provide.
It seems like this SendMessageA function is sending a keystroke one at a time.
So How to do this with ctypes.

edit：

Here is what I really wanna do:

I enumerate all the windows and found a particular one which is a file open dialogue popped up by the Flash in the Browser.

So I do find this Dialogue window and get it's hwnd(handler of the window)

Now I want to manipulate this window to select the file I want it to select.

The First thing I can think about is to enter the full path of file in the window and then press ENTER, this is kinda like mimic the way we select a file.

So, This is just How I approach this problem, if you got better solution, I am totally fine with it.

Thanks ahead if you could provide any hints.

Comment: Maybe the docs for the [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) function will help.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I already read the doc, but how to do this in python with ctypes

Comment: This appears to be an XY question. It seems that what you really want to do is fake input. It's far from clear that `SendMessage` is what you need. Indeed, it's far from clear that faking input is what you need. Very often it is the wrong solution. And finally, if you want to know about the parameters of `SendMessage`, you need to read the documentation. The fact that you believe `Msg` to be a string suggests that you cannot have read and understood the documentation.

Comment: I just edited the question, could you guys tell me how to do this with ctypes in python

Comment: Well, `Msg` is not a string. There's no point proceeding until you get that mis-understanding cleared up. Nobody can tell you how to send a message whose `Msg` parameter is a string, because that's not how messages work. Your main problem is that you don't yet understand Windows messages. You cannot continue until you do understand them. Doing so starts by reading the documentation. Even better would be to read Petzold's book.

Comment: thanks @DavidHeffernan, I think I will do more research here.

Comment: FWIW, `SendMessage` is probably not the solution to your real problem. But you did not tell us your real problem. That's what we mean by an XY question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57019/discussion-between-castiel-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: You probably want to use an automation library rather than faking input.

Comment: I use selenium, an automation library for browsers, but it doesn't satisfy this demand.

Comment: Difficult to know what you are looking for. You seem to have gone quiet.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really trying to do is automate a Windows file dialog. Python has various automation frameworks. You could do worse than use [pywinauto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) for this task. Another option would be to bind to the platform automation library, UI Automation. That's relative easy using COM.

Comment: beneath pywinatuo, it's using the trick that I've been chasing. So why bother use a big module. all I need is just a snippet of code within it. I will look into pywinauto and find what I need. thanks David

Comment: Suit yourself. I guess you know best.